# Which local DB/NoSQL support TTL and key-value store?

Tags: database, key-value, nosql

I need a local key-value cache that support TTL. It need to have very powerful performance like hashmap and also support TTL for an entry. That would be cool if it can use local storage if memory is not enough.

Found LevelDB doesn't support TTL or batch delete. Sorry to pass this option because the performance  is very good.

Any idea that can fulfill the requirement?

- Local key-value system
- Fast
- Support TTL
- Make full use of memory and better can use local disk when memory is not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely look at [Aerospike](http://aerospike.com)

Some useful links:

[Architecture Overview](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/)

[Hybrid Storage](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/storage.html)

[TTL](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/data-model.html#metadata)

[Fast](http://www.aerospike.com/benchmark)

[Scalable](http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/5/6/the-quest-for-database-scale-the-1-m-tps-challenge-three-des.html)

Comment: I preferred an embedded db so that there would be no cost of network. But this Aerospike benchmark seems quite amazing. I am trying to run a test on server and check out if it meets the requirement. Thanks!